# NLTK 3.0 install in Python 3.0 64 bits-Window 10

Tags: python, nltk

I spent few hours trying to figure out how to install NLTK 3.0 in Python 3.0 64 bits. I found many resources. One resource indicates he/she was successful but link was not found as it was described at https://davejingtian.org/2012/10/08/nltk-install-nltk-for-python2-7-on-64-bit-win-7/. I have installed python 3.0 64 bits but not have any luck with NLTK 3.0 installation. How can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

Just easily use `pip` to install it. Don't bother running the installation executable for Windows since it doesn't automatically install all the necessary dependencies for you.

```
C:/> pip3 install nltk
```

If pip3 was not added to your $PATH yet,

```
C:/> python3 -m pip install nltk
```

Or

```
C:/> py -3 -m pip install nltk
```

Then just import it(replace `py -3` to `python3` if it doesn't work):

```
C:/> py -3
>>> import nltk
>>>
```